# Sticky scroll for two images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been trying to figure out how to create a sticky scroll effect on two images, basically like this: http://www.nationalgeographic.com/americannile/ 
(scroll down to see you will see the four images with sticky scroll effect)

I have tried some jQuery plug-ins but still couldn't figure out how to create the effect I wanted.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, or just a point in the right direction.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

What You want to do is apply some actions when document scroll position changes. Since You are using jQuery, there is plugin exactly for this functionality called ScrollMagic, and here are [the demos](http://janpaepke.github.io/ScrollMagic/examples/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

The link you posted uses the scrollr library:
https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr

I've also used this library and I just can recommend it to you. It is really easy to use, for basic animations you don't need any javascript, everything is done via `data-` attributes.

It even supports mobile devices to some extend.